# Как правильно в программе на python несколько раз подключаться к MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, telegram, бот

У меня есть бот *telegram*, написанный на *aiogram*, в котором работа с БД выведена в отдельный файл в отдельный class. В остальных файлах мне нужен доступ к этой БД.

Если мне в нескольких файлах нужен доступ к БД, то мне надо в каждом файле делать подключение к этому файлу и подключаться к БД, или же лучше в каком-нибудь отдельном файле сделать это подключение, и потом импортировать эту переменную?

Comment: Ну, наверное, удобнее сделать подключение в отдельном классе и потом работать через этот класс всем вашим классам.

Comment: Да, у меня сейчас так и сделано, и я вот думаю потом это не скажется на эффективности работы бота